# wordpress changing host breaks image links

Tags: migration

I recently migrated my wordpress install from godaddy to a VPS that I setup. So far, everything but the images works. Not too sure why, but the images in posts appear broken, though if they are clicked on they will open the correct image. I've looked for a solution, but everything seems to be related to changing domains, whereas my domain remains the same, just redirected.

Thanks,

Comment: Edit your answer to include the errors that are in your webserver's error log.

Comment: I've run into this before.  You'll need to first locate where your current wordpress installation is looking for the image files, then check your config file to make sure it's configured for the new server.

Comment: Can you post a link to a page with broken images and explain where to look (if it isn't obvious)?

Answer (score 0):

The images were all in the same location as the original server, when you clicked on them, they load, though they display a broken link.

I gave in and transferred it to a namecheap account (the VPS is just used for testing and development, if it worked, yay, if not, no big loss) everything seems to work fine on it. Not too sure what the issue was, I'm assuming that I set my server up incorrectly, I think file permissions incorrectly set, but I can't be sure.

Not an answer, but a solution isn't necessary at this moment.

Thanks anyway

edit:
I checked the logs and it does indeed seem to be a permissions issue:

[Mon Jul 22 16:36:16 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] PHP Warning:  touch(): Utime failed: Permission denied in /home/user/www/wp-content/themes/showtime_v3.3/scripts/timthumb.php on line 189

Though why new permissions are required I dont know...